# json value from raw file and display it edittext other than AutoCompleteTextView in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Main class made for the country code and its corresponding value ,have used hashmap is there any better way to to it other than AutoCompleteTextView

sample json value from raw  json file  {"countries":{"country":[{"7840":0.1565},{"7940":0.0497},{"79407":0.1487},{"79409":0.1487}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // private String mSource = "[{\"7840\":0.1565},{\"7940\":0.0497},{\"79407\":0.1487}]";
        private List<CountryCode> mCountryCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        private AutoCompleteTextView mEtKey;
        private EditText mEtValue;

        private CountryAdapter mAdapter;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            parseJson();
            initViews();
        }
     private void initViews() {
            mEtKey = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etKey);

            mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(this, mCountryCodes);
            mEtKey.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    try {
    mEtKey.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mEtValue.setText(((CountryCode) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getValue());
               // int value = Integer.parseInt(((CountryCode) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getValue());
               // value = value / 1;
              //  mEtValue.setText(String.valueOf(value));

            }
        });
    }catch(Exception ex)
            {ex.printStackTrace();};

            mEtValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etValue);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private void parseJson() {
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rates);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int ctr;
            try {
                ctr = inputStream.read();
                while (ctr != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
                    ctr = inputStream.read();
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.v("Text Data", byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
            try {
                // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of json.
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(
                        byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
                JSONObject jObjectResult = jObject.getJSONObject("countries");
                JSONArray jArray = jObjectResult.getJSONArray("country");
                String jsonStr = jArray.toString();

            try {
                JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject entry = entries.getJSONObject(i);
                    Iterator keys = entry.keys();
                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        String key = (String) keys.next();
                        mCountryCodes.add(new CountryCode(key, entry.getString(key)));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }}
```

Country ADAPTER--adapter activity for getting the value from raw file ,this is another activity for making adapter and dynamically getting the values.

```
public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context mContext;
    List<CountryCode> mItems, mTempItems, mSuggestions;
    /**
     * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
     */
    Filter dialFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = ((CountryCode) resultValue).getKey();
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                mSuggestions.clear();
                for (CountryCode code : mTempItems) {
                    // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                    if (code.getKey().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        mSuggestions.add(code);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mSuggestions;
                filterResults.count = mSuggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<CountryCode> filterList = (ArrayList<CountryCode>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                if (mSuggestions == null) {
                    mSuggestions = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    public CountryAdapter(Context context, List<CountryCode> objects) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItems = objects;
        mTempItems = new ArrayList<CountryCode>(mItems);
        mSuggestions = new ArrayList<CountryCode>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSuggestions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CountryCode getItem(int position) {
        return mSuggestions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyt_item, parent, false);
        }
        CountryCode code = mSuggestions.get(position);
        if (code != null) {
            TextView lblName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_key);
            TextView lblValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_value);

            lblName.setText(code.getKey());
            lblValue.setText(code.getValue());
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return dialFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: can anybody help me out

Comment: I am new to android took me a week for this but need better options for doing it.